# What is the target name when setting the package installer?

Tags: android, adb

So I want to set this package as my package installer with this code.

```
   pm set-installer com.google.android.packageistaller
```

After typing that code, I get this:

```
Must provide both target and package installer names
```

What is the target name?

Answer (score 0):

The `set-installer` command only sets the package (package installer) which installed a specific package (target). This is why it requires two package names.

For instance, if you wanted to set package `xyz.abc.app` to appear as though it was installed by Google play, you would run this: `pm set-installer xyz.abc.app com.android.vending`.